# Select type of authentication 2FA depend account attributes

Tags: java, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm using Keycloak 16.1.1 with config with 3 type custom SPA 2FA: SMS, Email, Telegram... to get OTP to verify after user give username/password:

[Keycloak Flow Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cV13.png)

Each user have some properties like this:
[User Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puQIC.png)

I need to find the way depend on attributes Each account can only see Type authentication 2FA with thoese properties set to "YES" ( Other will not appear to account select another way in Keycloak). Example images above that account can see 2 type 2FA are: SMS + EMAIL, telegram will not appear to account select.
I tried to custom SPA to condition but I am not clear to understand conditional of Flow in Keycloak.
Any idea to support me.